# Codificación de los datos en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, oracle-10g

Con `Microsoft SQL Server 2008R`, y utilizando `Integration Services` se genera un error al insertar registros en una tabla a partir del resultado de una `select` a otra `bbdd` en `Oracle`.

He configurado la salida de errores para intentar capturar el registro que genera el error. A continuación el contenido del fichero de error generado. `CEXCOM` y `CODCOM` son columnas de la `select` origen pero con el valor del registro (`row`) parece codificado.

**¿Cómo puedo averiguar el registro que falla y su contenido?**

Archivo Error.txt:

> C E X C O M ƒ            ÿÿÿÿ&              N I N T E R ƒ           ÿÿÿÿ&              C O D C O M ƒ           ÿÿÿÿ&
>        E r r o r C o d e       À
>         L  ÿÿÿÿ               E r r o r C o l u m n       Ä
>         P  ÿÿÿÿ             & ®2T‘          &                & ÞÀL             € Àˆ#   & ï™×4          &                & ï
>   € À…#   & ¸?–„G          &                & ú¨             ‚
>   À‹#   & ¾!±H          &                & ã¬             ‚ À”#

Comment: bienvenido/a a StackOverflow. Creo que sería buena idea que incluyas el código relevante sobre el insert y el mensaje de error que recibes en la UI. Te invito a leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Tienes razón pero no tengo nada más que la select inicial. Intentaré volver a ejecutar el proceso para capturar el error de UI.
Gracias **JuankGlezz** por los enlaces y tu tiempo.